# Add group/user on OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am setting up OpenLDAP for the first time, on RHEL6 and using Puppet to do the initial install/configuration.

I believe the configuration uses the slapd.d rather than slapd.conf method.

Basically, I believe Puppet has successfully created a Database which I want to use as the root of my configuration tree. This is the output of slapcat that shows this database created:

```
dn: olcDatabase={3}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {3}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap/
olcSuffix: dc=corp.f7
olcRootDN: cn=root,dc=corp.f7
structuralObjectClass: olcHdbConfig
entryUUID: 8fce2bda-78b8-1033-80d2-f79b693c6963
creatorsName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
createTimestamp: 20140526002936Z
olcAccess: {0}to * by * read
olcRootPW:: e1NTSEF9MGkzazlZdldwMVNpU1FNVjhnNDQ4MHJBNFUra0FUdTI=
entryCSN: 20140526010102.566286Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
modifyTimestamp: 20140526010102Z
```

Then following an example I found online, I am trying to feed the following ldif file into this command:

```
ldapadd -cxWD cn=root,dc=corp.f7 -W -f /tmp/static.ldif

# User account
dn: uid=jsmith,dc=corp.f7
cn: John Smith
givenName: John
sn: Smith
uid: jsmith
uidNumber: 10000
gidNumber: 10000
homeDirectory: /home/jsmith
mail: jsmith@dev.local
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
loginShell: /bin/bash
userPassword: {CRYPT}*
```

However, I simply get the following error output:

```
adding new entry "uid=jsmith,dc=corp.f7"
ldap_add: No such object (32)
```

I am not really sure what object it can't find...is it the dc=corp.f7?

How do I go about setting up groups and users in this database I created?

Thanks

Comment: what does `ldapsearch -x` print out?

Comment: @Daywalker # search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1

Comment: It seems like your initial config is wrong. `dc=corp.f7` seems not a correct name for OpenLDAP. (but i never tried). I would have used something like `dc=corp,dc=f7` and just start over with the setup. (and you got two `W`arguments in your ldapadd command, maybee a problem?) btw.: the [FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-ldap.html) helped me a lot with the understanding of OpenLDAP (i got both, a Debian and a FreeBSD OpenLDAP Server)

Comment: @Daywalker I've now tried several RDN combinations, but none of them work. Running SLAPD manually, I see this error when I try and do ldapsearch: "hdb_dn2id: get failed: DB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found". Not sure what's going on.

Comment: This error message does not directly mens what you would first interpret (as described on [this](http://lists.arthurdejong.org/openldap-technical/2011/01/msg00006.html) site) could you post the complete debug output (on pastebin for example?) Be aware of passwords, or clear text names you don't want anybody to show!! (search an replace them with bogus, but don't mess up the Logfile :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a parent object for your user, second, you can't use the dot in the dcObject, dc (domain component) takes only alphanumerics and hyphen (see [RFC4519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519#section-2.4))

```
dn: dc=corp,dc=f7
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
dc: corp
o: corp
```

(And you can't use dcObject as the only object class because it's defined as auxilliary, so you need a structural class to provide some scaffolding; organization will do nicely. You might want to read RFC4519 while you're at it :-))